# How to change Our website URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new in PHP so I faced some problem using URL redirect using `.htacess`.

My URL page look like this: `http://domain.com/blog_detail.php?id=blog_title`

But I want change URL using `.htaceess` like this: `http://domain.com/blog/blog_title`

I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on   # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ## respect real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d ## respect real directories
RewriteBase /                       

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

&%{QUERY_STRING} only if you want to pass other variables here and there like:

```
http://domain.com/blog/blog_title?lang=fr
```

for instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this code is not working, but if replaced forward slash to hypen then it's working properly..
 RewriteRule blog-(.*)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: It may be if your blog script is in folder and is accesible through http://domain.com/blog/blog_detail.php . In this case you must type correct path like `RewriteBase /blog/`. I have changed my answer. May be it will help you.